# getting rid of java nullpointerexception and arrayindexoutofbound exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

im getting these exceptions on random occurrences. Sometimes they occur.Sometimes they dont
Please run this code and help me in getting rid of them

```
package my.matcher;
```

//import java.util.Calendar;

public class Matcher {

```
/*public static class priceHeap{
    int price;
    int orderid;
    int quantity;

    priceHeap(){
        price = 0;
        orderid = 0;
        quantity = 0;
    }
}*/

//private int price;
//private int type;

public static class PriceNode{
    int price;

    int logid;
    public PriceNode(){

    }
}
PriceNode[] buyPriceHeap = new PriceNode[maxHeapSize];
PriceNode[] sellPriceHeap = new PriceNode[maxHeapSize];

public static int temp_logid = 0;

public static int orderNum=0;
public static int tradeNum=0;
public static int buyOrderNum=0;
public static int sellOrderNum=0;

public static int totalOrders=0;
public static int checkMatchReturn=2;
public static final int maxHeapSize = 40000;

//public static int[] sellPriceHeap = new int[maxHeapSize];
//public static int[] buyPriceHeap = new int[maxHeapSize];

public static int buyHeapSize = 0;
public static int sellHeapSize = 0;

   public static class Order{ 

    int orderid;
    int price;
    int quantity;
    int logid;
    Order(){
        orderid = 0;        
        price = 0;
        quantity = 0;
        logid = 0;
    }
}
public static final int maxOrders = 100;
public static int buyOrderArraySize = 0;
public static int sellOrderArraySize = 0;

Order[] buyOrderArray = new  Order[maxOrders];
Order[] sellOrderArray = new Order[maxOrders];

public void siftUpMax(int child){
    int parent , tmp1,tmp2;
    if(child != 0){
        parent = (child-1)/2;
        if(buyPriceHeap[parent].price < buyPriceHeap[child].price){
            tmp1 = buyPriceHeap[parent].price;
            tmp2 = buyPriceHeap[parent].logid;
            buyPriceHeap[parent].price = buyPriceHeap[child].price;
            buyPriceHeap[parent].logid = buyPriceHeap[child].logid;
            buyPriceHeap[child].price = tmp1;
            buyPriceHeap[child].logid = tmp2;
            siftUpMax(parent);
        }

    }
}


public void siftUpmin(int child){
    int parent , tmp1,tmp2;
    if(child != 0){
        parent = (child-1)/2;
        if(sellPriceHeap[parent].price > sellPriceHeap[child].price){
            tmp1 = sellPriceHeap[parent].price;
            tmp2 = sellPriceHeap[parent].logid;
            sellPriceHeap[parent].price = sellPriceHeap[child].price;
            sellPriceHeap[parent].logid = sellPriceHeap[child].logid;
            sellPriceHeap[child].price = tmp1;
            sellPriceHeap[child].logid = tmp2;
            siftUpmin(parent);
        }

    }
}


public void buyPriceHeapInsert(int num , int id){
    if(buyHeapSize == buyPriceHeap.length){
        System.out.println("OVerflow");
    }
    else{
        buyHeapSize++;
        buyPriceHeap[buyHeapSize-1] = new PriceNode();
        buyPriceHeap[buyHeapSize-1].price = num;
        buyPriceHeap[buyHeapSize-1].logid = id;
        siftUpMax(buyHeapSize-1);
    }
    return;
    }
public void sellPriceHeapInsert(int num , int id){
    if(sellHeapSize == sellPriceHeap.length){
        System.out.println("OverFlow");
    }
    else{
        sellHeapSize++;
        sellPriceHeap[sellHeapSize-1] = new PriceNode();
        sellPriceHeap[sellHeapSize-1].price = num;
        sellPriceHeap[sellHeapSize-1].logid = id;
        siftUpmin(sellHeapSize-1);
    }
    return;
}

public void buyPriceHeapDelete(){
    //int temp = buyPriceHeap[0];
    buyPriceHeap[0].logid = buyPriceHeap[buyHeapSize-1].logid;
    buyPriceHeap[0].price = buyPriceHeap[buyHeapSize-1].price;
    buyHeapSize--;
    if(buyHeapSize > 0){
        siftDownMax(0);
    }
    }//Need to find a better way to delete from heap in java.

public void siftDownMax(int parent){
    int left,right,max,tmp1,tmp2;
    left = (2*parent) + 1;
    right = (2*parent) + 2;
    if(right >= buyHeapSize){
        if(left >= buyHeapSize)
            return;
        else
            max = left;
    }
    else{
        if(sellPriceHeap[left].price >= sellPriceHeap[right].price)
            max = left ;
        else
            max = right;                            
    }
    if(sellPriceHeap[parent].price < sellPriceHeap[max].price){
        tmp1 = sellPriceHeap[parent].logid;
        tmp2 = sellPriceHeap[parent].price;
        sellPriceHeap[parent].logid = sellPriceHeap[max].logid;
        sellPriceHeap[parent].price = sellPriceHeap[max].price;
        sellPriceHeap[max].logid = tmp1;
        sellPriceHeap[max].price = tmp2;
        siftDownMin(max);
    }
}

public void sellPriceHeapDelete(){

    //int temp = sellPriceHeap[0];
    sellPriceHeap[0].logid = sellPriceHeap[sellHeapSize-1].logid;
    sellPriceHeap[0].price = sellPriceHeap[sellHeapSize-1].price;
    sellHeapSize--;
    if(sellHeapSize > 0){
        siftDownMin(0);
    }
}

public void siftDownMin(int parent){
    int left,right,min,tmp1,tmp2;
    left = (2*parent) + 1;
    right = (2*parent) + 2;
    if(right >= sellHeapSize){
        if(left >= sellHeapSize)
            return;
        else
            min = left;
    }
    else{
        if(sellPriceHeap[left].price <= sellPriceHeap[right].price)
            min = left ;
        else
            min = right;                            
    }
    if(sellPriceHeap[parent].price > sellPriceHeap[min].price){
        tmp1 = sellPriceHeap[parent].logid;
        tmp2 = sellPriceHeap[parent].price;
        sellPriceHeap[parent].logid = sellPriceHeap[min].logid;
        sellPriceHeap[parent].price = sellPriceHeap[min].price;
        sellPriceHeap[min].logid = tmp1;
        sellPriceHeap[min].price = tmp2;
        siftDownMin(min);
    }
}

public int buyPriceHeapMax(){

    int maxBuy = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<buyHeapSize;i++){
        maxBuy = buyPriceHeap[0].price;
        if(buyPriceHeap[i].price>maxBuy){
            maxBuy = buyPriceHeap[i].price;
        }           
    }
    return maxBuy;
}

public int sellPriceHeapMin(){
    int minSell = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<sellHeapSize;i++){
        minSell = sellPriceHeap[0].price;
        if(sellPriceHeap[i].price<minSell){
            minSell = sellPriceHeap[i].price;
        }           
    }
    return minSell;
}



/*public void setPrice(int p){
    price = p;
}
public void setType(int t){
    type = t;
}
*/
```

/* public void checkType(int t){
        if(t==1){
            System.out.println("Buy Order");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Sell Order");
        }
    }*/

```
public void checkMatch(int p,int t,int q,int id){


    if(t==1){//Buy
        buyOrderNum++;

        if(sellPriceHeap[0].price != 0 && sellPriceHeap[0].price < p){

            tradeNum++;
            int log_id = sellPriceHeap[0].logid;
             //System.out.println("The active Buy Order has been matched with a Sell Order");
            //System.out.println("Buy Order Price : " + p);
            //int x = sellPriceHeapMin();
            //System.out.println("Sell Order Price : " + x);
            quantityCheck(p,q,t,id,log_id);
            //System.out.println("Both the entries have been Removed from the storage");
            //System.out.println("Now We Move On to the next Entry");
            checkMatchReturn=1;
            return;
        }
        else{
            checkMatchReturn=2;
            }


}

    else if(t==2){//Sell
        sellOrderNum++;
        if(buyPriceHeap[0].price!=0 && buyPriceHeap[0].price > p){

                    int log_id = buyPriceHeap[0].logid;
                    tradeNum++;
                    //System.out.println("The active Sell Order has been matched with a Buy Order");
                    //System.out.println("Sell Order Price : " + p);
                    //int y = buyPriceHeapMax();
                    //System.out.println("Buy Order Price : " +y);
                    quantityCheck(p,q,t,id,log_id);
                    //System.out.println("Both the entries have been Removed from the storage");
                    //System.out.println("Now We Move On to the next Entry");
                    checkMatchReturn=1;
                    return;


        }
            else{
                checkMatchReturn=2;
            }
        }


    return;
```

}

```
public void buyOrderArrayInsert(int id,int p,int q){
    buyOrderArraySize++;
    int i = buyOrderArraySize-1;
    buyOrderArray[i] = new Order();
    buyOrderArray[i].orderid = id;
    buyOrderArray[i].price = p;
    buyOrderArray[i].quantity = q;
    temp_logid = i;
    //int index = Arrays.binarySearch(buyPriceHeap, i);

}

public void sellOrderArrayInsert(int id,int p,int q){
    sellOrderArraySize++;
    int i = sellOrderArraySize-1;
    sellOrderArray[i] = new Order();
    sellOrderArray[i].orderid = id;
    sellOrderArray[i].price = p;
    sellOrderArray[i].quantity = q;
    temp_logid = i;
}

public void quantityCheck(int p,int qty,int t,int id , int lid){
    int match = 0;
    if(t==1){

                match = lid;


        int qmatch = sellOrderArray[match].quantity;
        if(qmatch == qty){
            sellPriceHeapDelete();
            //System.out.println("Quantities of Both Matched Entries were same");
            //System.out.println("Both Entries Removed");
            return;
        }
        else if(qty < qmatch){
            int temp = qmatch - qty;
            sellOrderArray[match].quantity=temp;
            //System.out.println("The Active Buy Order Has been Removed");
            //System.out.println("The Passive Sell Order Has Been Updated");
            return;
        }
        else if(qty > qmatch){
            int temp = qty - qmatch;
            sellPriceHeapDelete();
            //System.out.println("The Passive Sell Order Has Been Removed");
            buyOrderArrayInsert(id,p,temp);
            //System.out.println("The Active Buy Order Has Been Updated and Added");
            buyPriceHeapInsert(p,temp_logid);
            removeSellOrder(match);
            return;
        }
    }
    else if(t==2){
        //Active is Sell Order

                match = lid;


        int qmatch = buyOrderArray[match].quantity;
        if(qmatch == qty){
            buyPriceHeapDelete();
            //System.out.println("Quantities of Both Matched Entries were same");
            //System.out.println("Both Entries Removed");
            return;
        }
        else if(qty < qmatch){
            int temp = qmatch - qty;
            buyOrderArray[match].quantity=temp;
            //System.out.println("The Active Sell Order Has been Removed");
            //System.out.println("The Passive Buy Order Has Been Updated");
            return;
        }
        else if(qty > qmatch){
            int temp = qty - qmatch;
            buyPriceHeapDelete();
            //System.out.println("The Passive Sell Order Has Been Removed");
            sellOrderArrayInsert(id,p,temp);
            //System.out.println("The Active Buy Order Has Been Updated and Added");
            sellPriceHeapInsert(p,temp_logid);
            removeBuyOrder(match);
            return;
        }
    }
}

public void removeSellOrder(int n){
    sellOrderArray[n].orderid=0;
    sellOrderArray[n].price=0;
    sellOrderArray[n].quantity=0;

    if(n < sellOrderArraySize - 1){
        for(int i=n+1;i<sellOrderArraySize;i++){
            int tempid = sellOrderArray[i-1].orderid;
            int tempprice = sellOrderArray[i-1].price;
            int tempqty = sellOrderArray[i-1].quantity;

            sellOrderArray[i-1].orderid=sellOrderArray[i].orderid;
            sellOrderArray[i-1].quantity=sellOrderArray[i].quantity;
            sellOrderArray[i-1].price=sellOrderArray[i].price;

            sellOrderArray[i].orderid = tempid;
            sellOrderArray[i].price = tempprice;
            sellOrderArray[i].quantity = tempqty;
        }
    }


}

public void removeBuyOrder(int n){
    buyOrderArray[n].orderid=0;
    buyOrderArray[n].price=0;
    buyOrderArray[n].quantity=0;

    if(n < buyOrderArraySize - 1){
        for(int i=n+1;i<buyOrderArraySize;i++){
            int tempid = buyOrderArray[i-1].orderid;
            int tempprice = buyOrderArray[i-1].price;
            int tempqty = buyOrderArray[i-1].quantity;

            buyOrderArray[i-1].orderid=buyOrderArray[i].orderid;
            buyOrderArray[i-1].quantity=buyOrderArray[i].quantity;
            buyOrderArray[i-1].price=buyOrderArray[i].price;

            buyOrderArray[i].orderid = tempid;
            buyOrderArray[i].price = tempprice;
            buyOrderArray[i].quantity = tempqty;
        }
    }
}
/*
void printBuyOrder(int[] a){
    System.out.println("The Buy Order List is : ");
    for(int i=0;i<buyOrderArraySize;i++){
        System.out.println(" Order ID = " + buyOrderArray[i].orderid);            
        System.out.println(" Price = " + buyOrderArray[i].price);
        System.out.println(" Quantity = " + buyOrderArray[i].quantity);
        System.out.println("---------------------");
    }
}*/

public static void main(String[] args){
    int inprice=0,intype=0,inquantity=0,inorderid=0,x=0;
    long startTime=0,endTime=0;
    Matcher ob = new Matcher();
    ob.buyPriceHeap[x] = new PriceNode();
    ob.sellPriceHeap[x] = new PriceNode();
    //Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    //int s1 = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i=0;i<maxOrders;i++){
        inprice = (int) (Math.random() *500 +1 );
        intype = (int) (Math.random() *2 +1);
        inquantity = (int) (Math.random() *100 +1);
        inorderid = i;
        orderNum++;

        //ob.setPrice(inprice);
        //ob.setType(intype);
        //System.out.println("orderid : "+ inorderid + " price : " +inprice + " type : " + intype + "quantity : " + inquantity);
        ob.checkMatch(inprice,intype,inquantity,inorderid);
        if(checkMatchReturn == 2){
            //System.out.println("No Matching Order");
            if(intype==1){


                    ob.buyOrderArrayInsert(inorderid, inprice, inquantity);
                    ob.buyPriceHeapInsert(inprice,temp_logid);

                //System.out.println("The Unmatched Order is then inserted Into the Buy Order List");
                }
            if(intype==2){


                    ob.sellOrderArrayInsert(inorderid, inprice, inquantity);
                    ob.sellPriceHeapInsert(inprice,temp_logid);

                //System.out.println("The Unmatched Order is then inserted Into the Sell Order List");
            }
                }
            }
    //int s2 = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    /*System.out.println("The Pending Orders in the lists are : ");
    System.out.println(" ~~~~~ Buy Order List ~~~~~ ");
    for(int x=0;x<buyHeapSize;x++){
        System.out.print(" "+ buyPriceHeap[x]);

        }
    System.out.println(" ~~~~~ Sell Order List ~~~~~ ");

    for (int y=0;y<sellHeapSize;y++){ 
        System.out.print(" " + sellPriceHeap[y]);
        System.out.println("");
        }*/
    //int timetaken = s2-s1;

    endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long timetaken = endTime - startTime;
    double timetakenS = ((double)timetaken)/1000000000;



    System.out.println("Number of Orders = " +orderNum);
    System.out.println("Number of Trades Generated = " +tradeNum);
    System.out.println("Number of Buy Orders = " +buyOrderNum);
    System.out.println("Number of Sell Orders = " +sellOrderNum);        
    System.out.println("Total Time Taken = " +timetakenS+" seconds");

    double orderRate = ((double)(orderNum))/(timetakenS);

    System.out.println("Order Rate = " +orderRate+" per second");
    double avgTime = (timetakenS)/((double)(orderNum))*1000000;
    System.out.println("Average Execution Time per Order = "+avgTime+" micro seconds"); 



    //System.out.println("Do You Want to Print the Pending Order Books?");
    //System.out.println("y/n?");

}
```

}

Comment: Too much code. On what line are you seeing these exceptions?

Comment: public void buyPriceHeapDelete(){
    //int temp = buyPriceHeap[0];
    buyPriceHeap[0].logid = buyPriceHeap[buyHeapSize-1].logid;
    buyPriceHeap[0].price = buyPriceHeap[buyHeapSize-1].price;
    buyHeapSize--;
    if(buyHeapSize > 0){
        siftDownMax(0);
    }

Comment: im getting an arrayindexoutofbound on the `buyPriceHeap[0].logid = buyPriceHeap[buyHeapSize-1].logid;` line.....similarly in the other delete function

Comment: and the null pointer exception in the `SiftDownMin` and `SiftDownMax` functions.

Comment: please help me...im unable to figure out why im getting it on random input....

Comment: @Jha - stop giving it random input.  Find an input that exhibits the problem and use that input to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you're getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` exception on the line:

```
buyPriceHeap[0].logid = buyPriceHeap[buyHeapSize-1].logid;
```

then obviously you need to check the value of `buyHeapSize`. That should show you instantly what the problem is.

It'll either be some value higher than the actual size of the array or it will be zero. In the former case, it's probably because you're not keeping it in sync with the *actual* array. In the latter, you're probably trying to delete from an empty heap.

Those are the *likely* causes which you should investigate. The question is of limited value to others here so I'm wary of investing too much time other than to say you should either step through it with a debugger or pepper your code temporarily with `System.out.println` statements (general advice rather than a specific fix).

Both these options will make you a better person, debugging-wise.